# Платформа для онлайн-кинотеатра

Tags: cms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, скрипт или CMS для реализации сайта кинотеатра онлайн. Пробовал Joomla, WordPress, MODx, — ничего хорошего они не дали. Компоненты либо платные, либо плохие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yupe](http://yupe.ru/)